# How to add background images for each id using fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar plugin

I built an example and I'm trying to show images as background like this:
[image: ima]

Each picture saved on table teachers is saved inside the app.

```
route: app/public/uploads/teacher/1/abc.jpg
route: app/public/uploads/teacher/2/def.jpg
```

The helper avatar_url shows:

```
/public/uploads/teacher/1/abc.jpg
/public/uploads/teacher/2/def.jpg
```

The issue is that I cannot correctly display each image from each teacher.

Table - Teachers

```
|id| |name|  |avatar|
  1   ABC    abc.jpg
  2   DEF    def.jpg
```

Table - Reservations

```
|id||teacher_id| |date_ini|  |date_end|
 1     1         2018-11-01  2018-11-01 
 2     2         2018-11-01  2018-11-01
```

Html code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventRender: function(event, element) { 
        element.find('.fc-event-title').append( '<br>'+event.teacher_id);
        element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background","url("+ event.teacher.avatar_url +") no-repeat right");
      }

    })
  });
</script>
```

I tried this code and didn't work:

```
element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background","url( event.teacher.avatar_url) no-repeat right");
```

I tried this code and it didn't work- the background option

```
element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background","url(<%= event.teacher.avatar_url %>) no-repeat right");
```

I tried this code and it didn't work- on the HTML code it displays "undefined":

```
element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background","url("+ event.teacher_id.to_s +") no-repeat right");
```

I tried this code and it didn't work- it is not displaying background:

```
element.find('.fc-event-inner').css("background","url("+ event.teacher.avatar_url.to_s +") no-repeat right");
```

I tried the above and it is not displaying.

I will appreciate suggestions and comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your very first code `.css("background","url("+ event.teacher.avatar_url +") no-repeat right");` should be right, as long as `event.teacher.avatar_url` contains a valid URL to a valid image which exists at the right location on your server. Unfortunately you didn't really give us any information by which we could verify that, so you'll have to debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the **background image** to the element directly as in below example, and make sure that you are getting the image URL in the response:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventRender: function(event, element) { 
        element.css("background","url("+ event.teacher.avatar_url +") no-repeat right");
      }

    })
  });
</script>
```